# Puppeteer: interact with dom in waitForSelector handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

When I use puppeteer js web crawler, in `waitForSelector` handler I can use `console.log` without trouble:

```
page
  .waitForSelector('input[value=update]')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('this is');
    console.log('it');
  });
```

But I have an error when I want to interact with DOM:

```
page
  .waitForSelector('input[value=update]')
  .then(() => {
    const inputValidate = await page.$('input[value=update]');
  });
```

This code triggers this error:

> const inputValidate = await page.$('input[value=update]');
>                                      ^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>       at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:537:28)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
>       at startup (bootstrap_node.js:158:16)
>       at bootstrap_node.js:598:3

Do you know how to intercat with DOM in a `waitForSelector` handler without trigger an error?

Comment: Might be a bug in puppeteer; try their forum/site.

Comment: You're missing `async` in `.then(() => (...)`. It should be `.then(async () => (...)`. I don't know if this will resolve your error though.

Comment: @tomahaug yes it is! thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
await page
  .waitForSelector('input[value=update]')
  .then(async() => {
    const inputValidate = await page.$('input[value=update]');
  });
```

Comment: I added await before this snippet. and worked for me. Thanks @Vivien